# Is it possible to wrap a C# singleton in an interface?

Tags: c#, interface, singleton

I currently have a class in which I only have static members and constants, however I'd like to replace it with a singleton wrapped in an interface.

But how can I do this, bearing in mind that every singleton implementation I've seen has a static Instance method, thus breaking interface rules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution to consider (rather than hand-rolling your own) would be to leverage an IoC container e.g. [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/).

IoC containers commonly support registering an instance against an interface. This provides your singleton behaviour as clients resolving against the interface will receive the single instance.

```
  //Register instance at some starting point in your application
  container.RegisterInstance<IActiveSessionService>(new ActiveSessionService());

  //This single instance can then be resolved by clients directly, but usually it
  //will be automatically resolved as a dependency when you resolve other types. 
  IActiveSessionService session = container.Resolve<IActiveSessionService>();
```

You will also get the added advantage that you can vary the implementation of the singleton easily as it is registered against an interface. This can be useful for production, but perhaps more so for testing. True singletons can be quite painful in test environments.

Comment: Sounds interesting - in your code sample what is 'container'?

Comment: @Surfbutler 'container' is the IoC container instance. In this case it is an IUnityContainer.

Comment: Thanks chibacity, and what about 'ActiveSessionService'? Is that an example singleton class name, or part of Unity? Sorry, bit brain dead tonight!

Comment: That's just an example class, replace with your own.

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this with interfaces since they only specify instance methods but you can put this in a base class.

A singleton base class:

```
public abstract class Singleton<ClassType> where ClassType : new()
{
  static Singleton()
  {
  }

  private static readonly ClassType instance = new ClassType();

  public static ClassType Instance
  {
    get
    {
      return instance;
    }
  }
}
```

A child singleton:

```
class Example : Singleton<Example>
{
  public int ExampleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

A caller:

```
public void LameExampleMethod()
{
  Example.Instance.ExampleProperty++;
}
```

Comment: This abstract class works for me. I absolutely made a little changes:
    `public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : new()
     {
      private static T _instance;
    
      private Singleton()
      {
      }
    
      public static T Instance
      {
       get
       {
        if (Equals(_instance, default(T)))
        {
         _instance = new T();
        }
    
        return _instance;
       }
      }
     }`

Comment: `ClassType instance = new ClassType()` can be replaced with `Lazy<ClassType> instance = new Lazy<ClassType>(() => new ClassType())` for deferred execution which is useful when your `ClassType` is expensive to initialize.

Answer (score 6):

You can make all the *other members* of your singleton implement corresponding members in an interface.  However, you are correct that the `Instance` property *cannot* be part of the interface since it is (and must remain) static.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can not have instances in C#, I think you only need to:

Implement the singleton pattern (yes, you'll need a static attribute or method to get the  instance, but everything else does not require to be static)

On the other hand, your singleton can implement an interface if you want, just remember that other classes can also implement that same interface